# Is go's net.Close() idempotent?

Tags: go

The `io.Closer` interface's [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Closer) says:

> The behavior of Close after the first call is undefined. Specific
> implementations may document their own behavior.

What about a `net.Conn`'s `Close()` function? Can I safely call it more than once?

Specifically I am wondering if I can `defer c.Close()` in case I early return for an error, but still explicitly call `c.Close()` rather than making the client wait for me to finish background processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `net.Conn` is an interface, so it depends on the specific implementation.

I checked the implementation in `TCPConn`, `UDPConn` and `IPConn` structs. They seem to contain [this implementation](https://golang.org/src/net/net.go?s=7045:7073#L192) of `net.Conn` interface.

This implementation propagates the `Close()` call to its underlying file descriptor, which means that on Unix systems [this function](https://golang.org/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go?s=2273:2300#L75) is then called.

We have to go even lower, since the next call is to the mutex that is used by the file descriptor.

If the connection is previously closed and mutex is freed, it seems that it returns false, and the file descriptor `Close()` function returns [ErrNetClosing error](https://golang.org/src/internal/poll/fd.go?h=ErrNetClosing#L20).

So, I'll be free to say that you shouldn't call it more than once, as it will return an error in cases such as this one that I described. But it also may not error out in others. As the documentation says - it's undefined behavior.